# How to include assets for xhdpi devices on Android 2.1 application?

Tags: android

I have a Android application using 2.1.  I've gone ahead and created a drawable-xhdpi folder and put assets in it. I've set targetSdk=15, but the drawable in that folder is not being used.  Is it not possible to support newer devices and keep an minimum sdk of 7?

Comment: Just by having the drawable-xhdpi folder defined should be enough for the Android OS to read them. Presumably they are named identical to resources in drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi folders? also how do you know the aren't being using?

Comment: You need the other folders too. Assuming your device is xhdpi it will take from that given folder. Else it will look for the other folders (hdpi, mdpi, ldpi)

Comment: Just to be sure - do you have an xhdpi device or emulator?

Comment: I have a red image for xhdpi and blue one otherwise for testing , but I think my problem was my emulator. Read in google's docs to test xhdpi in emulator, resolution has to be 640*960. If I switch to that resolution , I get the right image. If I use the wxga720 skin which I thought was the skin to use for the s3,I get the wrong image. Both have 320 density set.